# como sacar un array dentro de otro array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Al hacer una consulta de `mysql` en `php` con `CodeIgniter`, me queda un array dentro de otro array y no se como ponerlo para sacarlo

```
public function getDetalleArticulos($id_consumo){

    $this->db->select("id_articulo");
    $this->db->from("detalle_consumo");
    $this->db->where('id_consumo', $id_consumo);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result=$query->result_array();
    // print_r($result);

    if (isset($result)){
      for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
        $data=$result[$i];
        print_r($data);
      }
      return $data;

    }else{
      return 1;
    }
}*
```

**y este es el resultado que me arroja:**

> Array ( [id_articulo] => 1 ) Array ( [id_articulo] => 2 )
>   A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Array to string conversion
>   Filename: pedido/Devueltas.php
>   Line Number: 45
>   Backtrace:
>   File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/grados20192/application/controllers/pedido/Devueltas.php
>   Line: 45
>   Function: _error_handler
>   File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/grados20192/index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once
>   Array

Alguien sabe como puedo obtener ese 1 y 2 guardarlos en una variable y pasarla al controlador para poder operar, gracias de Antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentarlo con un foreach.

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $data .= value['id_articulo'].',';
}
```

Lo que me queda en duda es los valores que arroja $result=$query->result_array(); antes de que pases el bucle for. Si puedes mostrarlo.

Comment: Lo que me arrojaba era lo que puse abajo: Array ( [id_articulo] => 1 ) Array ( [id_articulo] => 2 ), pero como dijo ethgar, el problema era que quedaba como matriz y por eso no sacaba bien el dato. Al reescribirlo en $data=$result[$i]['id_articulo']; dentro de un for, quedo la informacion que necesitaba en $data.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione, muchas gracias a todos los que respondieron, lo que hice fue:
$data=$result[$i]['id_articulo'];

De esta forma en $data quedó un Array con las variables que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

El resultado de la consulta la regresa en una matriz, por lo que accederás $consulta[0]['campo'], esto para un registro devuelto, si son mas, pues ya recorre lo con un for o foreach., de hecho si solo retornas un solo resultado puedes extraer el array y te quedarán los indices del mismo como variables, algo asi:

```
extract($consulta[0]);
echo $nombre; #imprimirá el valor del indice 'nombre' de tu resultado.
```

Comment: Excelente, quedo muy clara la informacion.